# Multiple instances of the same view with different timer

Tags: objective-c

I have a custom view named "car". I use an NSTimer to animate this "car" view which was added previously to my subviews.

```
-(void)createRedCar
{
  //-- here I create my first car
  [self.view addSubview:car];

  //-- here I initiate a timer to move the car
  myTimer calls 'moveCar' method
}
```

Then I can this method to move the car across the screen

```
-(void)moveCar
{
car.transform //-- here I move the car across the screen
}
```

Everything works as expected.

I'm having troubles creating new instances of "car" and animate them exactly as I did first time. Any ideas?

If I try to call "createRedCar" method again, it will just add a new car to the screen without calling the "moveCar" method to animate it.

How can I create multiple "car" views and animate them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with 'move' being set as a variable used by all cars. You can do something along the lines of:

```
- (void)createCar
{
    UIView *car = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 10)];
    [car setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:car];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(moveCarWithTimer:) userInfo:car repeats:YES];
}

- (void)moveCarWithTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    UIView *carToMove = [timer userInfo];
    [carToMove setFrame:(CGRectMake(carToMove.frame.origin.x+1, 0, 40, 10))];
}
```

That moves the frame based on the frame of the current car. I tried this in a new project with createCar being called every time I tapped a button. As long as you wait long enough to tap the button again, you'll see the new car running separately from the old one.

Comment: can you see my latest answer to this question? it shows the actual code

Comment: userInfo can't handle an object directly, only thru NSDictionary. So yes, I passed the _car object view NSDictionary as you suggested and doesn't work, as the _car object is created again, I will work only until I call again 'moveCarWithTimer'

Comment: I've revised the answer, hopefully that helps.