# Multiple NSTimer animation views

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

```
- (void)createCar
{
    _car = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 10)];
    [_car setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self addSubview:_car];

    _myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:normalSpeedValue target:self selector:@selector(moveCar) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)moveCar
{
    static int move = 0;
    move = move+1;
    [_car setFrame:(CGRectMake(move, 0, 40, 10))];
}
```

This is how I create a view and animate it moving from left to right.

If I call the method "createCar" again, it will just create a new view but I won't animate. Why is that?

I want to be able to create more views and animate (moveCar).

Comment: Why did you post a new question instead of updating [your previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961009/multiple-instances-of-the-same-view-with-different-timer)?

Comment: What is your `normalSpeedValue` set to?

Comment: @hola normalSpeedValue = 0.01

Comment: In addition to the other answers about not managing the cars in an array or removing the old car, you never reset `move` back to 0.  Move needs to be a property or iVar rather than a static local so that you can reset it in `createCar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that additional calls to `createCar` creates motionless, but still visible cars, is because the callback on the timer, `moveCar`, only has reference to the most recently created car stored in the `_car` ivar.

The past created cars are still visible because the view they were added to still holds reference to them and consequently continues to draw them.

You can fix this by creating an `NSMutableArray` for your cars, adding them to it in `createCar`, and then looping over the array moving each car in the `moveCar` method.

Sample Code:

```
// ...
NSMutableArray<UIView *> *_cars; // Be sure to init this somewhere
// ...

// ...
timer = NSTimer.schedule ... // Schedule time in viewDidLoad, or somwhere
// ...

- (void)createCar
{
    UIView *_car = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [_car setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview: _car];

    [_cars addObject:_car];
}

- (void)moveCars
{
    // go through each car
    [_cars enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *car, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
        // and set its frame.x + 1 relative to its old frame
        [car setFrame: CGRectMake(car.frame.origin.x + 1, 0, 100, 100)];
    }];
}
```

This is one simple way of doing it. But if you want flexibility like different speeds for different cars, it'll take a little reworking but not much.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Every time your move became 0 when method get called. declared it as instance variable and set it's initial value 0 (in your case) in `createCar` method. I think this you want. hope this will help :)

Comment: static variables are declared once and then exist for the lifetime of your program. The declaration is not repeated, and the increment works.